# lost connection to mysql server at reading initial communication packet, system error:34 in sqlyog

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, mariadb, sqlyog

I am using the server

AWS linux
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"

DB
Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server

I want to use a sql tool which is sqlyog using putty with this sql server
But when i try to connect the server
it says lost connection to mysql server at reading initial communication packet, system error

[sqlyog connection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtPwp.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5Ub.png)

server ip:port number(33)
server ip:3306(sql port) i've tried this too
Could anybody helps what's wrong ?

Comment: Try if you can establish a connection via telnet, if not then there is a problem with your ssh tunneling but not with MariaDB.

Comment: Thank you for the comment 
I've tried to change DB password strongly and it worked